# N:M Relationship between users and guests

Tags: sql, database, sequelize.js

I'm building an app that can assign guests to an existing user. Those guests can see some information about the users they are associated with.

It's `N:M`:

- Users can have multiple guests associated
- Guests can be associated to multiple users

Under the hood they are stored in the same table, the only difference between them is the role they have.

(My real table have more fields like password etc... but those are not relevant to this question)

[image: User table]

I need to create a table like this:

[image: guests table]

The thing is that `userId` and `guestId` are referenced to the same column (`id`) of `Users` table.

Is this viable?

Comment: i think you don't need to associate guestId with user table only userId association can work . if you want i can share code for the same .

Comment: "Is this viable?" -- Yes. What's the specific question?

Comment: Yes, this looks okay. Both IDs refer to a user in the users table, so you'd have two foreign keys, one for each column. You'd also have a unique constraint on the pair. I'd rather call the IDs `host_user_id` and `guest_user_id`, though, to make their roles obvious and indicate they are both user IDs. But can a user only be either a guest or a host?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner user cannot have more than 1 role, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can only be either a guest or a host. This is why you have a role column in your user table.

Your guests table contains two users in a row, and as I mentioned in the request comments, I'd call them `host_user_id` and `guest_user_id` to make their roles obvious and indicate they are both user IDs.

The table design is okay for that. The only downside is that you could mistakenly make a host a guest and a guest a host, because the guests table is not aware of which is which, both are mere user IDs. If you want the database to guarantee consistency in this aspect, this gets a tad more complicated. Here is a design that deals with this problem:

```
create table users
(
  id         not null int,
  full_name  not null varchar(100),
  role       not null varchar(10),
  created_at not null timestamp,
  updated_at          timestamp,
  constraint pk_users primary key (id),
  constraint chk_users_role check (role in 'host', 'guest'),
  constraint unq_users_role unique (id, role)
);

create table guests
(
  host_user_id  not null int,
  host_role     not null varchar(10),
  guest_user_id not null int,
  guest_role    not null varchar(10),
  constraint pk_guests primary key (host_user_id, guest_user_id),
  constraint fk_guests_host foreign key (host_user_id, host_role) references users (id, role),
  constraint fk_guests_guest foreign key (guest_user_id, guest_role) references users (id, role),
  constraint chk_guests_host_role check (host_role = 'host'),
  constraint chk_guests_guest_role check (guest_role = 'guest')
);
```

This doesn't look as nice as before, as `host_role` being constantly `'host'` and `guest_role` being constantly `'guest'` looks redundant to us human readers, but it guarantess that a `host_user_id` really refers to a host user and a `guest_user_id` to a guest user.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
create table users (
    userId int generated always as identity primary key,
    fullname varchar(255),
    . . .
);

create table guests (
    guestId int generated always as identity primary key,
    fullname varchar(255),
    . . 
);

create table userGuests (
     userGuestId int generated always as identity primary key,
     userId int references users(userId),
     guestId int references guests(guestId
);
```

You can then load these as:

insert into guests (fullname, . . .)
    select distinct fullname
    from old_users
    where role = 'guest';

insert into users (fullname, . . .)
    select distinct fullname
    from old_users
    where role = 'user';

```
insert into userGuests (userId, guestId)
    select u.userId, g.userId
    from old_users ou join
         old_users og
         on ou.id = og.id join
         users u
         on ou.fullname = u.fullname join
         guests g
         on og.fullname = g.fullname
    where ou.role = 'user' and og.role = 'guest';
```

Note:  This all uses generic SQL syntax, but it should give the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know why it wouldn't work. I would change the name of the guests table though just to make it more clear that it doesn't hold the guests, but the guests relations.